# Specifying $MANPATH after installing coreutils doesn't affect the man page displayed

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, bash, homebrew

I installed the GNU core utilities via `brew install coreutils`. I also added `PATH=$(brew --prefix coreutils)/libexec/gnubin:$PATH`
 to the beginning of `~/.bash_profile` (and it's auto-sourced in `~/.bashrc`) as to enable accessing these utilities with their default names, ant not prepended with `g`.

I also want access to the `man` pages of these utilities, so I added `MANPATH="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnuman:${MANPATH-/usr/share/man}"` to `~/.bash_profile` as the second line. Unfortunately, when I type `man ls` for example, I still get the BSD man page, instead of the Gnu one. How do I fix this?

Comment: .bash_profile should source .bashrc i.e. the opposite way to the way you have said https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html but that is probably not the issue

Comment: what does `echo $MANPATH` show?

Comment: @Mark /usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnuman:/usr/share/man

Comment: What happens if you- `man gcat`?

Comment: The I get the man page for GNU cat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so after researching about `$MANPATH` with regards to Linux\UNIX, I came across the idea of adding `export MANPATH` right after defining it in `~/.bash_profile`. This solves the problem as required, i.e. giving me access to `man` pages for `coreutils`, and only then to their BSD versions, if no GNU version exists.